# ReactJS How to add additional image To props and change them on Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties, ecmascript-6

Hello im trying to add an second image to my image props and change them on click any suggestions how can i solve it? here is my bin
[my react bin](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmWYIwPrjZiZPwmAAwg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example of how you can do this.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'

class FadeImage extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props, context, images) 
  {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       index: 0,
       imageClass: 'image'
     };

     this.fadeImage = this.fadeImage.bind(this);
  }

  fadeImage(e) 
  {
     e.preventDefault();

     var s = {
       index: (this.state.index + 1) % this.props.images.length
     };

     if (this.state.imageClass === 'image') 
     {
       s.imageClass = "image-loaded";
     } 
     else
     {
       s.imageClass = "image";
     }

     this.setState(s);

     console.log('clicked');
  }

  render() 
  {
     return (
       <div>
         <a href="#" onClick={this.fadeImage}>Change Me!</a>
         <img src={this.props.images[this.state.index]} />
       </div>
     )
  }
}

render(<FadeImage images={['http://via.placeholder.com/350x150', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x151']} />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

Note that its perfectly fine to keep image paths in props. But you do need to have a current image index in state. Also there is no need to call `setState` multiple times. You can prepare your updates as part of one object and introduce all of them at once.

Answer (score 2):

Your image `src` needs to be listening for a `state` and not a `props`. Props is immutable and State is mutable.

Comment: yeah the question is how :/ problem is i have to mix state and props and don'r realy know how

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an array of images as props.

```
render(<FadeImage images={["http://via.placeholder.com/350x150", "http://via.placeholder.com/350x151"]} />, document.querySelector('#app'))
```

And you update piece of state (`currentImage`) that doesn't exists. Change it to :

```
this.setState({
   index: (this.state.index +1) % this.props.images.length
});
```

And if will work.

[Here is your Bin.](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KmWa0BdeWcv9t-lM67N)